# Código de HTML no visible

Tags: html

En una página de la empresa necesito visualizar la posición de un elemento en el código **html** y cuando lo quiero ver a través de la función: `document.getElementsByClassName("caret")`  me aparece exactamente así:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("caret") 
<HtmlCollection length="10">
</HtmlCollection>
```

Como ven no se alcanza a apreciar los 10 elementos correspondientes a la clase `caret`

Entonces quería ver la forma de visualizar la posición exacta de esos 10 elementos. Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Has probado con DevOps? -> click derecho en el elemento inspeccionar

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero me sigue apareciendo solo la clase del elemento y yo lo que quisiera saber es la posición del mismo.

Comment: En realidad no comprendo la pregunta. Quizás te falta alguna etiqueta (solo tienes HTML) o en realidad mejorar la explicación de lo que quieres lograr. Un saludo.

Comment: Una disculpa, trataré de ser más explícito. Requiero ver los 10 elementos que pertenecen a la clase `caret`, aprieto **F12** para visualizar el código, me voy a la parte de la consola, ahí coloco lo siguiente: `document.getElementsByClassName("caret")`, me indica que hay 10 elementos de la misma clase, ahora quiero saber su posición de cada elemento correspondiente a dicha clase entonces le doy click para que me desglose en forma de lista esos 10 elementos pero no me aparece nada, como si estuvieran ocultos, entonces ahora lo que quiero es saber como visualizar esos 10 elementos.

Comment: No se si dispones del código fuera de ejecución, si es así puedes realizar una busqueda más fácilmente desde ahí, el comando para abrir la búsqueda suele ser `ctrl+f` ahí escribes `caret` y podrás verlo, en caso de que no lo dispongas, a lo mejor con `document.getElementsByClassName("caret")[0]` te muestre solo el primer elemento, si es así, con un `for` puedes obtener todos